# twitter Login Callback android app

Tags: android, twitter, authentication, callback, twitter4j

I'm trying to login on twitter from my android app using Twitter4j library but it crashes when the callback is called... and appears this screen:  the page is not disponible

this is my code:

```
        public class TwitterLogin extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Twitter twitter;
    RequestToken requestToken;

    /*
    * Calls the OAuth login method as soon as its started
    */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //      setContentView(R.layout.main);
            OAuthLogin();
        }

    /*
    * - Creates object of Twitter and sets consumerKey and consumerSecret
    * - Prepares the URL accordingly and opens the WebView for the user to provide sign-in details
    * - When user finishes signing-in, WebView opens your activity back
    */
        void OAuthLogin() {
            try {
                twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                twitter.setOAuthConsumer(TwitterConstants.CONSUMER_KEY,TwitterConstants.CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY);
                requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterConstants.CALLBACK_URL);
                Log.w("TwitterLogin requestToken callbackUrl: "+requestToken.toString());
    //          requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuth.OUT_OF_BAND);
    //          String pin = requestToken.getParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);
                String authUrl = requestToken.getAuthenticationURL();
                Log.w("TwitterLogin requestToken authUrl: "+authUrl);
                this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
                Log.w("TwitterLogin despres del startActivity intent");
                } catch (TwitterException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("in Main.OAuthLogin", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }


    /*
    * - Called when WebView calls your activity back.(This happens when the user has finished signing in)
    * - Extracts the verifier from the URI received
    * - Extracts the token and secret from the URL
    */
        @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            super.onNewIntent(intent);
            Log.w("TwitterLogin  dintre del onNewIntent");
            Uri uri = intent.getData();

            Log.w("TwitterLogin uri: "+uri.toString());

                if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TwitterConstants.CALLBACK_URL)){

                    try {
                        String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
                        Log.w("TwitterLogin","onNewIntent oauth_verifier: "+verifier);
                        AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
                        Log.w("TwitterLogin","onNewIntent accesToken: "+accessToken.toString());
                        String token = accessToken.getToken(), secret = accessToken.getTokenSecret();
                        displayTimeLine(token, secret); //after everything, display the first tweet

                    } catch (TwitterException ex) {
                        Log.e("Main.onNewIntent", "" + ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }

        }

    /*
    * Displays the timeline's first tweet in a Toast
    */

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        void displayTimeLine(String token, String secret) {
            if (null != token && null != secret) {
                List<Status> statuses = null;
                try {
                    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(token, secret);
                    statuses = twitter.getFriendsTimeline();
                    Toast.makeText(this, statuses.get(0).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error:" + ex.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("Main.displayTimeline",""+ex.getMessage());
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Not Verified", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

if someone can help me please, I've been trying to login on Twitter 2 days and I don't know how to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you provided callback URL for your app when registering you app on twitter.?

if you have provide callback URL then use same in android client...

because you are making request with callback

requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterConstants.CALLBACK_URL);

then server also replies with callback after login is successful to twitter.

Comment: When I registred my app on twitter dev in callback I put some url and then on Android Manifest I wrote:
- scheme="x-oauthflow-twitter"
- host="callback"

it's correct?

Comment: if I do this:
requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();

it returns to the callback that I wrote on twitter dev settings callback_url and it works, but If I put:

requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterConstants.CALLBACK_URL); then it shows Web Page not avaliable.. why??

Comment: it is necesary to put some webView? I'm doing all without one of them! 

can someone help me please?